# Get the value when a MySQL constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

Assuming I am inserting rows in a MySQL table with a constraint

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `child` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_parent` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_parent_child` (`id_parent`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_parent_child` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`),
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Then when I do an insert in the `child` table without the entry in the `parent` table:

```
INSERT INTO child (id, id_parent) VALUES (1, 1);
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`...`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `FK_parent_child` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`))`
```

But is there a way to retrieve the value of the insert-failed row, aka `1` here? Because when I insert thousands of rows at the same time, it would be very useful to get the failed one.

I would like a fully-MySQL way, but a PHP way would work too in my case.

Comment: Check the presence of a parent before inserting

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in that will tell you which constraint failed.

Comment: @Mike This is like saying "Do the Foreign key check in your client code (PHP)", which totally wipes out the concept of a SQL foreign key

Comment: @Barmar And is there such feature in another SQL server (Oracle, Microsoft, Maria or whatever)?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use any of those other databases.

Comment: @Xenos foreign key serve to prevent inconsistent data in case of errors in the application. By the way, how do you insert a few rows for 1 time?

Comment: @Mike "Insert a few rows for 1 time"? Ie "in what case do you have to insert multiple rows at once"? Well: DB set up/update, bulk importing (ie from Excel file or so), bulk treatment,...

Comment: @Xenos I mean, if you do separate inserts - you can check the completion of each of them and all ID in your hands. If the overload from another table - you can make error-free insertion and  separately query to get all the inappropriate rows. Other ways, especially in the MySQL does not exist

Comment: @Xenos With a strong desire can create trigger for prevents insert errors. And log error records to anower table